# Having trouble identifying this probability distribution and its parameters

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, normal-distribution, gamma-distribution

For $y = \frac{1}{4}\text{ }x\text{ }e^{-x/2}$, my initial hunch was that it is a normal distribution but I wasn't able to figure out what the mean and variance would be. What is it? What are its mean and variance?

Comment: 1. Is this for some subject? If not, how does the question arise? Either way, it lacks context. 2. Note that hunches are not a good way to make progress in statistics. (It's clearly not normal, since it has an "$x$" out the front of the exponent and lacks any $-x^2$ type term in the exponent -- did you even try to draw it?) 3. Is this meant to be a density function for a continuous variate on the positive half-line, or something else? 4. What distributions do you know about? What [search and research](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) have you done on this?

Comment: sorry i should've been more clear. This is a probability density function for a continuous RV. I derived this from a joint multivariate density function. It's an example from my statistics course and on top of just finding the prob density, the question is asking to identify the distribution of y.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a previous answer has suggested, it appears the support for this distribution is:

$$x\in[0,\infty)$$

To verify it as a density, we can integrate across the support and the area should be equal to 1:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x/2}\,dx&=\frac{1}{4}\Big[-2xe^{-x/2}\Big]_{0}^{\infty}+\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}2e^{-x/2}\,dx\\
&=0+\frac{1}{4}\Big[-4e^{-x/2}\Big]_{0}^{\infty}\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

Now, as to *what* density this is, note that the $\text{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$ density has the form:

$$f(x)=\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}$$

If we let $\alpha=2$ and $\beta=0.5$, this leads to:

$$f(x)=\tfrac{1}{4}xe^{-x/2}$$

Thus, your distribution is that of a $\text{Gamma}(2,0.5)$. This verifies the mean and variance calculations:

$$\begin{align}
E[Y]&=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=4\\
\text{Var}(Y)&=\frac{\alpha}{\beta^{2}}=8
\end{align}$$

This also confirms the support we defined above. One way that such a Gamma distribution can arise, for example, is if we have:

$$X_{i}\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda=0.5)$$

where all $X_{i}$ are independent and
$$Y=\sum_{i=1}^{2}X_{i}$$

then
$$Y\sim\text{Gamma}(2,0.5)$$

As to why you might think it is a normal distribution, you should note that the equation for $y$ does not follow the form of a normal density at all. Further inspection of the plot of $y$ shows that the density is skewed, which should tell you immediately that it cannot be normal.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Evidently the range of this RV is $(0, \infty)$, because that's how you get the density to integrate to 1.

The mean is $$\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 {\rm exp}(x/2) dx = 4$$

This is easy to solve using integration by parts.

Through a similar (but more tedious) calculation, you can find that the second moment is

$$\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^3 {\rm exp}(x/2) dx = 24$$

which means the variance is $24 - 4^2 = 8$.

Comment: right thanks for that, but looking back at the graph. it doesnt seem normally distributed

Comment: The density function you specified is not that of the normal distribution.

Comment: @DerekFrank, For one thing, it's the density of a positive random variable. And, second, it's skewed. So the normal distribution has nothing to do with this. Not sure why you think it does.

Comment: In case it is of help... $\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 {\rm exp}(\color{red}{-}x/2) dx = 4$?

Comment: @AntoniParellada, Yep. Looks like a typo.